# Dataframes from Elasticsearch in PySpark with Jupyter

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm a newbie in data science - so apologize my basic questions...

I am working on a small project, where I extract data from Elasticsearch and would like to work with them in Jupyter.

For connecting to Elasticsearch I use

```
docs = spark.read.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').options(**options).load('syscalls*/doc')
```

The connection works fine, even it takes a while to extract the data (about 40.000.000 documents).

*What I wanted to do next:*

For test purposes I would like to work on a small set of data containing only one column

```
testcnr = docs.select('test_nr').withColumn("test_nr", docs["test_nr"].cast("int"))
```

This works fine. When I'm trying to create a small sample set with

```
test_sample = testcnr.sample(False, 0.000001, seed=0)
```

it seems, that jupyter continues working on the whole data set (testcnr), because it takes the same time as querying only the sample DataFrame (test_sample). Where am I wrong?